# Updating field based on button clicked

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have 3 ASPLink Buttons: Resolved, Unresolved, Cancelled

I want to be able to change the ResolutionStatusID field based on which button is clicked. I am unsure how to do this.

i.e.

When Unresolved button is clicked the value of the ResolutionStatusID = 3

When Cancelled button is clicked the value of the ResolutionStatusID = 4

When Resolved button is clicked the value of the ResolutionStatusID = 5

Code below

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [HardwareFault] WHERE [HardwareFaultID] = @HardwareFaultID" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [HardwareFault] ([FaultTitle], [ResolutionStatusID], [Message], [LoggedBy], [DateTimeLogged]) VALUES (@FaultTitle, @ResolutionStatusID, @Message, @LoggedBy, @DateTimeLogged)" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT dbo.ResolutionStatus.ResolutionName, dbo.HardwareFault.*, dbo.aspnet_Users.UserId, dbo.aspnet_Users.UserName FROM dbo.HardwareFault LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.aspnet_Users ON dbo.HardwareFault.LoggedBy = dbo.aspnet_Users.UserId LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ResolutionStatus ON dbo.HardwareFault.ResolutionStatusID = dbo.ResolutionStatus.ResolutionStatusID WHERE [HardwareID] = @HardwareID" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [HardwareFault] SET [ResolutionStatusID] = @ResolutionStatusID WHERE [HardwareFaultID] = @HardwareFaultID">



    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="HardwareFaultID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="1" Name="HardwareID" QueryStringField="HardwareID" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="FaultTitle" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ResolutionStatusID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Message" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="LoggedBy" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="DateTimeLogged" Type="DateTime" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ResolutionStatusID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>


<div>

<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="HardwareFaultID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style=""class="<%# Eval("ResolutionName") %>">

            <td>

                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" style="text-decoration:none; padding:3px 6px 3px 5px;" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Change Status">
                        <span class="icon16 icomoon-icon-cog-2" style="padding-top:7px;"></span>
                        <span class="caret" style="margin-top:10px;"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="top: 33px; left: -75px; min-width: 110px; font-size: 12px;">

                        <li>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="Resolved" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to change this fault to Resolved?');" runat="server" CssClass="miniDropdown">Resolved <span class="btn btn-success icon16 icomoon-icon-checkmark-2" style="text-decoration:none; padding:3px 6px 7px 5px;"></span></asp:LinkButton>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="Unresolved" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to change this fault to Unresolved?');" runat="server" CssClass="miniDropdown">Unresolved <span class="btn btn-info icon16 typ-icon-question" style="text-decoration:none; padding:3px 6px 7px 5px;"></span></asp:LinkButton>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="Cancel" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to Cancel this fault?');" runat="server" CssClass="miniDropdown" CommandName="Update">Cancelled <span class="btn btn-danger icon16 icomoon-icon-blocked" style="text-decoration:none; padding:3px 6px 7px 5px;"></span></asp:LinkButton>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:ListView>

</div>
```

Comment: So, what problem are you having? And don't say "it doesn't work".

Comment: I am not sure how to do this. I have tried a number of ways to update the field from the code behind, but I'm obviously not doing it correctly

Answer (score 0):

i think you should find the control of the link button of the listview and do whatever you want

in asp page

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="simjoblin" runat="server" OnClick="simjoblin_Click" CommandName='<%# Eval("ID")%>' class="ns_empoptions ns_similrjobs">
```

in c# page

```
protected void simjoblin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton jid = sender as LinkButton;
    string jobid = jid.CommandName;
//do what you want

}
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use **item command** feature of listview. Add **OnItemCommand** event, and place **CommandName='...'** **CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>'** in your LinkButtons.

```
<asp:ListView OnItemCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton CommandName='Resolved' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>' ID="Resolved"></asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:LinkButton CommandName='Unresolved' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>' ID="Unresolved"></asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:LinkButton CommandName='Cancel' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>' ID="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

C# Code (decide on **e.CommandName**):

```
protected void ListView1_ItemCommand1(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "Resolved":
            // do sth
            break;
        case "Unresolved":
            // do sth
            break;
        case "Cancel":
            // do sth
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```